# Brackets App Remove Auto Semicolon

Tags: adobe-brackets

Is there a way to remove the auto semicolon in Brackets App in the CSS auto complete from code hints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Brackets ever auto-inserts a semicolon in CSS currently. (Very early on it did, but that was removed [over a year ago](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/pull/2675)). Do you have any extensions installed, such as [Emmet](https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet)? An extension might be causing this behavior. If you're not sure, try *Debug > Reload Without Extensions* and see if it still happens (just restart Brackets again to re-enable all your extensions).

Comment: Uninstalling Emmet did the trick.  But now when i select a value (padding as an example), I hit return and instead of accepting the value it accepts it and gives me a new line (return).  I would like to try Brackets out more but behave like Sublime a bit more.

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s247/sh/350222a0-0f34-4542-b550-654fec91cc10/d09896517b36d7833d3e1ea07851475b

Comment: @Mando: It shouldn't insert a newline when you press Enter. It sounds like you may have another extension installed that's also causing trouble. Does it behave better after _Debug > Reload Without Extensions_? If not, can you give more precise steps about exactly what you're typing, where the cursor is when you press Enter, which code hint you're selecting, and how you're selecting it?